# Servername directive in Apache

Tags: apache

I am setting up a local Apache server on my Ubuntu laptop to do some development work. I have a site up on AWS that is called xxxubantiator.com. I have  written a chrome extension that talks (via Ajax) to this server. The extension connects to the xxxubantiator/Register and all works AOK (in both directions). I am concerned that if I name my local apache2 server the same thing, there will be an issue with knowing if I am talking to the local server or the AWS server. Is there some way that I can name my local server xxxubantiator.com but tell my extnesion that I am referring to the local server, not the remote server? The remote server is https while the local is http.

Comment: You can use `ServerName google.com` if you want. Your server won't get any request unless you fiddle with your DNS or hosts file.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is "fiddling".

Comment: Convince your computer that the IP address of `google.com` is `127.0.0.1`.